# AWS Athena - Create table and assign the first row as header columns

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have a use case where I need to create Athena tables out of tab-delimited files stored in my folders in S3. All of these files have first row as header columns - and each file could have a different set of columns that are not known to me beforehand.

What's the best way to create an Athena table by reading the file from S3 and assigning the first row as column names? (**Given** that all columns' types would be `varchar` and all files would be tab-delimited.)

Looking for something like-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_database.my_table
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '    ',
  'field.delim' = ' '
) LOCATION 's3://path/to/folder/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');   -- 'derive_column_names_from_first_row'='true'?
```

Comment: Doesnt work like that. You'd have to create a crawler in glue to figure out the schema, then likely create the table for you

Comment: oh okay, thanks @NeilMcGuigan

Comment: Even crawling this data will not help as table created will have full file path which is not supported by Athena. For this to work you need to have different schema files in different folders and then crawling them via Glue crawler.